# Is this a good start for custom iOS UI?

Tags: ios, swift

*As a beginner, I have to say that understanding how to create custom UIs and how Cocoa/UIKit work in general is pretty complex for me, so I am experimenting...*

So here is some code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.bounds.width-20, height: 300)
        let roundedRectangle = UIBezierPath(rect: myRect)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        shapeLayer.path = roundedRectangle.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 2
        shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)            
    }
}
```

I understand it pretty well, it gives me this result :
[image]

I want to understand several things :

- Is this a good way to draw a custom UI element ? What is Apple generally using to do that ? Could I make complex and beautiful UIs using CA ? Or should I override the drawRect method ?
- I have got a rectangle with a shadow, but lets say that I wanted to react to the user touching it, what should I use ?

Comment: If you don't really need to draw custom shapes/paths etc, it'd be better to use a simple rectangle with it's layer's `masksToBounds` set no `NO` (false) and shadow properties set as you desire. Using custom layers, you can almost do everything, but you'd be going lower-level. As a beginner, of course feel free to experiment with layers etc to understand the inner workings, but I'd just go with a regular view.

Comment: If you're trying to draw a rounded rectangle, you can use `self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;` assuming `self.myView` is a UIView. You can also do the same for UIButton. You might have to additionally include `self.myButton.clipToBounds = true;`.

Comment: You could use several ways to get the touches on elements. Adding a clearColor UIButton, adding a UITapGestureRecognizer or even checking in hittest what has been pressed.